# Is the Subversion client for Windows available with no registration required?

Tags: version-control

Basically, I want to get an update of the standard command-line subversion client for Windows. I used to be able to get downloads of this quite easily, but it seems like registration is required these days.

I object to registration, but equally, I prefer not to use workarounds that e.g. involve registering with details that won't stay valid.

I already have TortoiseSVN - this isn't about clients in general, but specifically about the standard command-line client. I also don't need the server stuff - just the client.

It looks like I *can* download the source, but building from that probably involves the usual dependency-finding issues and so on. As this is likely to be a recurring issue, I'd prefer to avoid it if possible.

I'll be more than happy with a torrent link. Googling for that specifically, though, just leads to a lot of what look like pirate versions of commercial clients.

Any ideas? Or is there some good reason for collecting these registration details that might override my objections?

**EDIT**

Applogies to everyone I "sigh"ed at or whatever over SlikSVN suggestions. Clearly, I need to do better at avoiding making bad assumptions.

Comment: where did you download your svn cmd client?

Comment: The last time I downloaded the standard client was version 1.6.6 - the installer is labelled as collabnet. I don't recall needing to register for that. Obviously I've missed a few versions since - mostly because I couldn't find a registration-free download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, you can certainly download and build the [source code](http://subversion.apache.org/source-code.html#source-release); it's free software under the [Apache License 2.0](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0).  But if you want to download an executable without Collab's registration, try [SlikSvn](http://www.sliksvn.com/en/download).

Comment: SlikSVN is not the standard subversion client. As I said, I already have TortoiseSVN - this isn't an any-client-will-do thing.

Comment: @Steve, there *is* no standard binary SVN client; Although Collab does employ several SVN developers, their client is not standard.  The SVN project is very [clear](http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html) on this: "The Subversion project does not officially endorse or maintain any binary packages of the Subversion software."

Comment: @Matthew - there's still a big difference between a build of the standard source package and a build of a different client completely. A build of the standard source package is the standard client, irrespective of whether it is an official endorsed binary. Note - I never said "standard binary package" - only "standard client".

Comment: @Steve: the thing is, they *are* builds of the standard source package.

Comment: OK - next question... How come I was so convinced that it was an alternative client with a GUI etc? That's left me feeling pretty stupid (a familiar feeling just recently, I have to say).

Comment: I don't know.  They link several GUIs from the [download page](http://www.sliksvn.com/en/download/), but none of them are part of SlikSVN, which is just a command-line build of the standard source (currently SVN 1.6.12).

Comment: Acceptance for making me see my mistake (ie the comment was more important than the answer).

Answer (score 2):

Which site are you downloading from?  Just taking a look at the download links from the SVN project home (http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html), I see four options for Windows, several of which do not have registration, at least.  The SlikSVN link is free and has command line utilities.

You could also install Cygwin, which is definitely free and comes with other useful utilities.

Comment: It includes the standard client.  It actually appears to be the CollabNet build, if you look at svn --version.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a free one here:

http://www.sliksvn.com/en/download

Answer (score 1):

Binary distributions of the subversion client are available from the official subversion site.

http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html

Comment: As soon as you click on a specific link, you are taken to a registration page. This is not an answer to the question I asked.

Comment: @Amber and @Steve314: I did read the question. Not every link on the page asks for registration. SlikSVN, for example, which is on the link I provided, offers direct download.